# How to use redis-cli to export the values of a list only?

Tags: bash, shell-script, redis

I am trying to export all values of a redis list using `redis-cli` as a list of strings in shell scripts. However, there are some unwanted text that I couldn't get rid of.

For the following list `q1`:

```
redis:6379> 5 lpush q1 "{\"id\":1}"
(integer) 1
(integer) 2
(integer) 3
(integer) 4
(integer) 5
redis:6379>
```

If I export it directly using `LRANGE`, the result has a row number and a parenthesis at the beginning of each line (which needs to be removed).

```
:/# redis-cli -h redis LRANGE q1 0 -1
1) "{\"id\":1}"
2) "{\"id\":1}"
3) "{\"id\":1}"
4) "{\"id\":1}"
5) "{\"id\":1}"
```

If I use `redis-cli --csv`, there is a comma between values (that needs to be removed):

```
:/# redis-cli -h redis --csv LRANGE q1 0 -1
"{\"id\":1}","{\"id\":1}","{\"id\":1}","{\"id\":1}","{\"id\":1}"
```

*How can I make redis export just the list values, one in each row?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my laptop `redis-cli`, using the `--raw` command-line option produces output with just the plain list values.  I.e., without the "1)", "2)", etc. prefixes.

Redis version 6.0.9 added the `--raw` command-line option to `redis-cli`, so older versions won't support it.